# Add gopath by project in go-plus atom

Tags: go, atom-editor

Im trying to set a different **GOPATH** for every project, I have achieved this on vs code and intellij idea, somehow there is no easy way to do this is someone know I will appreciate some help.

Use case: We use a gopath per project here at work, and seems like go-plus only support one afaik.

Comment: I don't understand _I have achieved this on vs code and intellij idea, somehow there is no easy way to do this_

Comment: Out of interest: What's your use case for that requirement?

Comment: The use case is that I need to set up a gopath per project and seems like go-plus package does not support it.

Comment: You might take a look at the package atomenv. However, it did not work for me.

Comment: I just read through the open issues for go-plus on Github. To me it looks like the author is working on the issue by adding support for a .go.json configuration file that will allow for a variety of scenarios at binary, library and project level.

Answer (score 3):

In atom, you can install package [atomenv](https://atom.io/packages/atomenv). Once installed, you need to add a file at the root of your project, named `.atomenv.json`. This will help you to set variable environments per project in atom.

For GOPATH, edit the file `.atomenv.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "GOPATH": "$HOME/go:$ATOM_PROJECT_PATH"
  }
}
```

(`$HOME/go` is where your main gopath is, for example)

Then you need to call `atomenv:load` (CTRL+SHIFT+P atomenv:load).

If you use go-plus, the (i) go tab will now show your new GOPATH!